# Div center the screen instead of on the top when linked from navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

When I try to use the same page linking in HTML, it brings the DIV on the top of the page. I would like to center it on screen.

The navigation bar:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li id="navitem"><a href="index.html#someitem">Div1</a></li>
        <li id="navitem"><a href="index.html#someitem">Div2</a></li>               
     </ul>
</div>

#navlist
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display:none;
}
```

Div:

```
<div id="someitem"> </div>

#someitem
{
  padding: 15px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;    
}
```

Comment: You can place the dummy div `display: none` above the real div and link to it.

Comment: Actually. This works fine - for now :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you were looking for?

```css
#navlist
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li id="navitem"><a href="index.html#someitem">Div1</a></li>
        <li id="navitem"><a href="index.html#someitem">Div2</a></li>               
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It still brings the div behind the navigation bar when clicking the link